# Record SQL used for Postgresql Import Tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using the Postgresql Import tool to populate my development database with data from CSVs.

Is there a way to 'record' what SQL the import tool used to run the import. For example, I go through and select Filename, the encoding, whether there are headers, what the delimiter is, which fields to populate etc.

As there is a bit of 'trial and error', once I have successfully done this, I then want to just copy the SQL and save it later in Evernote so I can run that next time when I need to repopulate the database (truncate then reimport etc). I could then also possibly use that SQL for a ruby rake task so I can run it from the terminal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Postgres Import tool? It sounds like you're using a 3rd party app?

Comment: Ah sorry, using PgAdmin3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that PgAdmin-III's "import tool" does is run the `COPY` command. If you enable `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and examine the server logs you'll see it.

You can instead use the `psql` `\copy` command from a script to achieve the same thing.

This won't work with SQL run via other clients, though, as `COPY` is a special command that switches into a special line-by-line input mode that things like the Ruby Pg gem generally don't support directly. [The Pg gem *does* support `COPY` via the `copy_data` method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#copy_data-instance_method), so you can use it from Ruby code, but then you have to open the CSVs yourself in Ruby, etc. It's pretty simple, and that's how I'd do it if I wanted to use a Rake task.

Another option is to use server-side `COPY`, where you pass PostgreSQL the path of the file to load directly. This is fastest, but requires the PostgreSQL server to have permission to read the file, and the file to be on the same computer as the server. So it's not very flexible.

I recommend using the Pg gem with `copy_data` in your Rake script.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I do use the COPY command but as I do a lot of trial and error I thought if I could easily see a log of what was actually being actioned by using the wizard I can then just do a copy of that for next time. Your solution seems like the way to do it, although now it seems easier to just master the copy method ha. Thanks again.